# Which tense is correct for a subordinate clause in indirect (reported) speech?

Tags: reported-speech, subordinate-clauses

Here are a couple of examples with which I'm struggling.

> He said that they had been living separately for 2 months before they
>   got divorced (or had got divorced) in June.

Should it be either of these: divorced or had got divorced, or both are fine and perfectly ordinary English? Perhaps, the latter is more formal, isn't it?

A similar example:

> He said that man had been drinking for the whole year before he
>   sobered up (or had sobered up?).

Comment: Or perhaps "before they **were** divorced in June."

Comment: Yes, get divorced is ok in speech. So, if he said it, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

"He said that man had been drinking for a year, or had been drinking all year before he sobered up".

"had been drinking" is past perfect continuous tense, which is used to indicate that it had been in progress until another point in the past = he sobered up. The period of drinking happened before getting sober, that's why the past perfect continuous is used, so you only need to use it once.